# Infinitive and Gerund Difference: "refused to pay" or "refused paying"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1. She refused **to pay** the penalty.
> 2. She refused **paying** the penalty

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: The first one is right. The second is wrong. No idea why, I'm just a native English speaker.

Comment: To refuse a payment is to refuse to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**refuse** in this context means **to express a determination not to (do something)**.

Therefore the structure **refuse to + infinitive** is needed. (e.g. I refuse to go to school)

---

For more information on this structure and on the usage of gerund have a look at this:

- https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-by-the-infinitive
- https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-by-the-ing-form

Comment: When you copy wording from somewhere (in this case the definition "to express a determination not to (do something)"), you need to indicate that it's copied and where it came from. Please [edit].